# Not able to refer to any project resources without fully qualified name

Tags: android, android-resources

I am not able to refer to any of my project resources without the fully qualified package name

like com.mypackagename.abc.R.layout.menu_item_layout
 instead if using `R.layout.menu_item_layout` my project's `target sdk is api level 19` and `minimum required sdk is api level 10` and `compatible with api level 17'. Why iam not able to
refer the resources in the normal way.can anyone find any fix for this

Comment: Are you also importing `android.R`?

Comment: Is the source file in the same package as `R`?

Comment: @Tanis.7x android.R was there in the imports and i removed it and that worked. I haven't noticed that import statement. thanks for your time, :-)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes. And the problem was with i,port statements as i have android.R got imported somehow and now it is fixed. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove all **R** imports from that Class.
2. save the files
3. Now import the correct **R** file

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports... probably you have wrongly imported "android.R".

Comment: I would add that checking the build path would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You have imports problem. Try manually adding:

```
import com.mypackagename.abc.R;
```

And make sure that R is not already imported. Because you are not allowed to import more than one file with same name. The solution is to use full package name in code as you are now.

Comment: @Gazam deleted android.R and imported com.mypackage.abc. and that fixed my problem. thanks for your time :-)